# How To Keep My File Paths Congruent for My Django/Python Application

Tags: python, django, bash, unix

I am developing a Django app on my Personal Computer. I have my files uploaded to a private repository on GitHub and I am using that to pull them down to my production server.

**My question is this**

I have file paths set inside of my application on my *PC* to file locations that are on my *PC*. But I also have those same files being uploaded and pulled onto my *Production Server*, but then needing to change the file path on my *Production Server* side application files in order to match the actual location on my *Production Server*

I have searched far and wide and cannot seem to find a proper solution to this. Is there some type of way I can write out the paths so that when I use an `sys.path.append` I don't have to give out the complete path, but rather a local one, so that it matches on both servers?

**Possible Findings**

Is there an issue if I just use `sys.path.append('./<directory>')`? This is, of course, assuming that the Python file is running within that current directory.

Comment: How about use `.env` of `pipenv` to define different environment variables?

Comment: I'm not sure what paths you are referring to. There shouldn't be any need to hard-code paths at all. What specifically is the problem? Show some code.

Comment: Mainly, it’s the path for my passwords file such as the secret key, my email password, and database password